# Matrix dimension error while calling mldivide in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

I am getting this error while running my code:

> > Error using ==> mldivide Matrix dimensions must agree.

Here is my code :

```
%make the plots of phase and group velocity vs discreteness of the grid
c=1;

a=input('Please enter the ratio cdt/dx : ')

figure(1)
R=2:40;
plot(R,phase_vel(R,a)/c)
xlabel('R=l/dx')
ylabel('u_phase/c')

%figure(2)
%plot(group_vel(R,a),R,0,40)
%xlabel('R=l/dx')
%ylabel('u_group/c')
```

and here are my functions :

```
function phase_velocity = phase_vel(R,a)
    %numerical phase velocity of the discrete wave 
    c=1;
    phase_velocity=(2*pi*c)/(R*knum(R,a));
end

function group_velocity =group_vel(R,a )
    %numerical group velocity of the discrete wave
    c=1;
    group_velocity=(a*sin(knum(R,a)))/(sin(2*pi*a/R))
end

function knumber = knum(R,a)
    %This is the k wave number
    knumber=acos((1/a)^2*(cos(2*pi*a/R)-1)+1);
end
```

How can I resolve this error?

**EDIT:** I used . operator in every equation and i changed the limits of R=4:40

Comment: I don't have the Symbolic Math Toolbox, which it looks like you're using, so the following questions may be clueless: (1) Is it in the first `plot` or the second that you get the error? (2) If the first is OK and the second isn't, does it help if you say `omega=2*pi/R/dt;` instead of `omega*dt==2*pi/R;` so that there isn't an equation-solving in there?

Comment: You provided many lines of code, it would be **very** helpful to know in which line of what function your code fails.

Comment: Hello,the problem is exactly in the plot command (the first plot)at the first script.Both plots give me the same errors.(i tried omega=2*pi/R*dt,but still the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to apply your formulas to each individual value in the vector `R` then you should be performing all of your computations using the [element-wise arithmetic operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) `.*`, `./`, and `.^` instead of the matrix operators `*`, `/`, and `^`.

Your error is probably occurring in the first call to your function `knum`, specifically when you try to compute `2*pi*a/R`. Since `2*pi*a` is a single scalar value, you get an error when trying to perform [matrix right division](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mrdivide.html) `/` using the row vector `R`. The *really* weird thing is the error message:

```
??? Error using ==> mldivide
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

which implies you are using the matrix *left* division operator `\`, which you clearly aren't. I tested this in MATLAB R2010b and I get the same incorrect function name appearing in my message. I think this may just be a typo in the error message, and I've dropped a note to the MATLAB folks to take a look at it and clear it up.

Comment: @George: Did you replace *every* `*` and `/` with `.*` and `./`?

Comment: @George: Then you shouldn't still be getting that exact same error message, unless the error is coming from another part of your code that you didn't include above. What other information (i.e. line number) does your error message contain?

Comment: @gnovice:I included everything.(and thans for helping).Here are the other errors: Error in ==> knum at 4
knumber=acos((1/a).^2.*(cos(2.*pi.*a/R)-1)+1);

Error in ==> phase_vel at 5
phase_velocity=(2.*pi.*c)/(R.*knum(R,a));

Error in ==> phase_plot at 8
plot(R,phase_vel(R,a)/c)

Comment: @gnovice: I just realized that i didn't use . at every / !! Sorry!I missed it!Now,its ok! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Symbolic Math Toolbox, but your problem seems to be that you are using `plot`, a function which can deal with arrays of numbers, and feeding it the result of a symbolic calculation. Have a look at the Matlab Help, where the Topic [Creating Plots of Symbolic Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/brvfu8o-1.html#brvfxfs-1) suggests using `ezplot()`. Alternatively you need to evaluate your symbolic expression for certain input values to create an array of numbers that `plot` can deal with - but you can't use double() for that since it wouldn't know what numbers to plug into your variables.

Comment: Hello, the ezplot takes function handles (if i am not wrong) but i have two functions which i want to retain.As for the input values you said to create an array ,i didn't understand what do you mean.

Comment: If I read your code correctly, you are trying to plot your function phase_vel with R going from 0 to 40. This is not at all a syntax plot can deal with. As I said I can't test it here, put give this a try: plot(0:40,double(phase_vel((0:40),a)/c) ... this tries to hand an array of R-values to your function, convert the results to a double (ie. numeric) array and hand these to the plot function.

Comment: Hello,thanks for the help.I tried it and it gives me " Error using ==> mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double
array."